# Hide mapbox and planet (or other tilemap) API from the frontend

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox, svelte, dotenv

I'm trying to hide the access token/api key from the client side. I'm using svelte (not sveltekit) with `dotenv` to store my keys.

.env

```
MAPBOX=someaccesstokenkeys
PLANET=someaccesstokenkeys
STYLE=stylefolder/styleid
```

The map worked just fine, no error. But when I check the source from the element inspector, the keys are still not hidden.

[image]

[image]

Are there any alternatives? or I have to redo this in sveltekit?

EDIT:
I've tried svelteKit, put my secretkey on `.env`, and import from `page.server.js`. From there, I return the data (I don't know any way other than this) and I assume this also expose the secretkey on client-side.

+page.server.js

```
import { MAPBOX, PLANET, STYLE } from '$env/static/private'

export async function load() {
  // this will expose to client-side
  return {
    mapbox: MAPBOX,
    planet: PLANET,
    styleid: STYLE
  }
}
```

Are there anyway to hide it from the client-side?

Comment: I think you cannot hide it in client. You need to create a proxy server to serve your client. Your server will forward the request and adding the secret key and return the data back to the client without the client knows what is the secret key.